# How to get value from Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe, angular2-observables

Please have you any idea how to get `_value` from:

[image: this]

I have this function:

```js
jobsLength(){
   const jobslength:any;
   jobslength=this.searchLogic.items$
   console.log(jobslength)
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **subscribe** to the `items$` Observable to get the data.

```js
jobsLength() {
   this.searchLogic.items$.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
       let jobs: any[] = value;
       console.log(jobs);
       console.log(jobs.length);
   });
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfkagk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

### References

[Observable (Subscribing)](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing)